# html5-canvas pattern size fluctuations

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a problem with createPattern(). First i define a canvas and pass that as source for a pattern, to be applied on a second (larger) canvas - just as in this demo by epistemex:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/dn7bvjh0/
```

This works fine. However, when i call the function below multiple times, each time changing the size of the 'receiving' canvas ('canvasContext'), the size of the canvas fluctuates. The larger the canvas, the closer the elements of the pattern are placed to each other. As this creates a break in the rhythm when canvasses (of different sizes) are placed next to eachother, i am looking for a solution!

```
var unit = heightNow/2;

var canvasPattern = document.createElement("canvas");
canvasPattern.width = unit;
canvasPattern.height = unit;
var pctx = canvasPattern.getContext("2d");

pctx.beginPath();
pctx.fillStyle = basicClrs1[woordNummer];
pctx.rect(0,0,unit,unit);
pctx.fill();
pctx.beginPath();
pctx.fillStyle = basicClrs2[woordNummer];
pctx.rect(0,0,unit/2,unit/2);
pctx.fill();
pctx.lineWidth = unit/4;
pctx.stroke;

var pattern = canvasContext.createPattern(canvasPattern,"repeat");
canvasContext.fillStyle = pattern;
canvasContext.rect(0,0,widthNow,heightNow);
canvasContext.translate(0,0,widthNow,heightNow);
canvasContext.fill();
```

http://automatto.nl/img/pattern.png

Comment: Can you provide a complete example? It's not clear what heightNow and widthNow are, and I'm not sure if all the code you have provided is included in the function. I have created [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k982dxa7/) but I'm not sure if it matches what you are doing.

Comment: If the canvas width and height differ at any time then this may cause a 'break in the rhythm', because the pattern size is dependent on the height alone.

Comment: on every page load new divs are generated, with different widths and heights ('widthNow' and 'heightNow'). but both are always exact multitudes of the variable 'unit' - the size of the pattern-module - so i expect the pattern to be in sync with the height en width. this is not the case, the larger the div, the more unexpected fragments of the 'next' pattern-module  are visible at the right and bottom.

Comment: The image you linked to shows that vertically you are getting a sliver of the next copy of the pattern; this is because the height of the canvas is an odd number, this wouldn't happen with an even number. With the height being odd, the pattern-module includes half a pixel so it inevitably cannot be displayed properly. Regarding the width, are you sure that it is a multiple of unit? In the image it doesn't look like it is, and the code does not enforce that it be a multiple of unit (though it does for height).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes the width is, like the height, a multiple of unit for sure. I doesn't look like that because the pattern mysteriously shrunk a little. Same happens here: https://jsfiddle.net/czjdwk4h/ If you change the unit-value, the pattern sometimes fit and sometimes not.

Comment: In your fiddle, heightNow is set to 300/8 = 37.5. It seems that a canvas can only contain whole pixels so it floors the width and height, setting them to 37 instead. After 8 repetitions of the 37 pixel-wide pattern, we have used 8 * 37 = 296 pixels of the 300 pixel-wide canvas, so it fills the remaining 4 pixels with another repetition of the pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is occurring where the pattern height (and width) - `unit` - is not an integer. The canvas that is used for the pattern has its height and width rounded down. When the pattern is repeated the intended number of times there ends up being a few left over pixels which get filled with an additional part of the pattern.

This unwanted effect could be worked around using scaling.

Just replace the last line (the call to fill) with the following:

```
var repetitionsX = Math.floor(widthNow / canvasPattern.width);
var repetitionsY = Math.floor(heightNow / canvasPattern.height);
var scalingFactorX = widthNow / (canvasPattern.width * repetitionsX);
var scalingFactorY = heightNow / (canvasPattern.height * repetitionsY);
canvasContext.save();
canvasContext.scale(scalingFactorX, scalingFactorY);  
canvasContext.fill();
canvasContext.restore();
```

Comment: Thanks Jon, that is solving the problem! In this case i could even solve it (after reading your comment above) by taking care 'unit' (of which the width and height are multiples) is always an integer. But if that is not possible, the scaling is good work around. One should only be aware pattern-elements like circles could be ovals after scaling. Thanks again, i really appreciate your help!